# find a specific piece of text after a specific a tag with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

given the following setup:

```
<a href="foo">Subject</a> &gt; 
<a href=bar">Negotiation</a>,
```

1) Is it possible to select the "&gt"; that is located to the right of this a tag with jquery?
 I do not    want   to select all "&gt"; on the page I am trying to find specific ones.

I tried .next() and .text() with jquery with no success.

I do not have access to the code as it is dynamically created from the backend which I have no access to so I need to do this with a document.ready

Comment: You can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery), the example with DOM methods should do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would get the `&gt;` -

```
$("a[href='foo']").get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/hugwm/